# Como fazer uma expressão regular que ache um nome e depois procure um caractere?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Eu estava analisando um extenso código html que contém basicamente este formato:

```
<span id="mensagem" class="topo">Classes e comandos</span>
```

O problema, é que a quantidade de argumentos dentro de span variam de quantidade e posição

O objetivo é obter o conjunto "**Classes e comandos**".

Para isso, preciso que quando a busca ache  a sequência "**mensagem**", procure o próximo caractere "**>**" e, quando achar, pegue a sequência de caracteres à frente que forem diferentes do caractere "**<**".

Assim:

```
           (achou)--------------v(achou) 
<span id="mensagem" class="topo">Classes e comandos</span> 
                                 ||||||||||||||||||x(chega nesse e para)
                                   (pega esses)
```

Só falta expressar isso em expressão regular. Estou usando o notepad++, alguém saberia formular uma expressão regular para este problema?

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação você está utilizando ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o próprio Notepad++, mais específico:  Localizar, Localizar com a opção "expressão regular" selecionada.

Comment: Tente o seguinte: `<span[^>]+>(.*?)<\/span>`

Comment: Veja funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/VQ8gry/1)

Comment: É muito próximo disso amigo Wéllington. No site regex101 ele separa o texto em Grupo 1, mas no notepad ++ ele seleciona tudo entre as tags. É quase isso, ele só precisa excluir as tags e capturar apenas o texto entre elas. Grato pela sugestão.

Comment: Leitura recomendada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4438007

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta**
Assim como mencionado pelo usuário Wellington, você deve seguir os passos:

> Vá para Pesquisar-> **Substituir**.
>   Defina o valor do campo Pesquisar/Localizar: `(<.*?(?=mensagem).*?>)(.*?)(<.*?>)|(.*)`
>   Defina o valor do campo Substituir com: \2 ou $2.
>   Defina o modo de busca como: **Expressão regular**.
>   Clique no botão: **Substituir tudo**.

Isso vai substituir todo o texto pelos conteúdos que possuem a palavra chave **mensagem** dentro da tag.

[Você pode testar essa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/Df2Aqy/1/)

*Caso não tenha resolvido o seu problema comente aqui o que esperava, o que aconteceu de errado e tento resolver, espero ter ajudado :D*

**Explicação da Regex**
Essa regex possui 4 grupos de capturas, vou explicar o que cada um faz para que possa entender melhor

```
(<.*?(?=mensagem).*?>)
```

O **grupo 1** vai capturar tudo que está entre a tag, isso se possuir a palavra mensagem em qualquer posição antes do caractere "**>**", para isso usei um *positive lookahead*, ele determina que tudo entre `(?=` e `)` é uma condição para captura do que está antes.

```
(.*?)
```

O **grupo 2** só será acionado caso o grupo 1 capture algo, já que está na mesma expressão e não está depois de um operador **OU**, ele captura tudo menos quebras de linhas e para assim que outro caractere da expressão seguinte for encontrado.

```
(<.*?>)
```

O **grupo 3** captura tudo que está entre as tags após o grupo 2, a tag "**<**" também serve como um limitador para que o grupo 2 pare de capturar quando encontra-lo.

```
|(.*)
```

O **grupo 4** é uma expressão que está depois do operador **OU**, isso significa que caso a regex não capture com a expressão anterior, irá tentar capturar com essa, logo só inseri um operador "**.**" para capturar qualquer caractere que não seja quebra de linha (`\n`), então tudo que não corresponder com sua pesquisa irá ser apagado ao substituir tudo pelos conteúdos do grupo 2.

Answer (score 1):

Siga os passos:

> Vá para Pesquisar-> Substituir.
>   Defina o valor do campo Pesquisar/Localizar: **<span[^>]+>(.*?)</span>**
>   Defina o valor do campo Substituir com: \1 ou \2.
>   Defina o modo de busca como: **Expressão regular**.
>   Clique no botão: **Substituir tudo**.

Lembrando que ele vai deixar apenas o resultado encontrado, **exemplo:**

```
<div>
   <span id="mensagem" class="topo">Texto 01</span>
   <span id="mensagem" class="topo">Texto 02</span>
   <span id="mensagem" class="topo">Texto 03</span>
   <span id="mensagem" class="topo">Texto 04</span>
   <span id="mensagem" class="topo">Texto 05</span>
</div>
```

Fica apenas:

```
Texto 01
Texto 02
Texto 03
Texto 04
Texto 05
```

Comment: Como explicado na pergunta, span pode vir com argumentos em posições, nomes e tamanhos diferentes: (exemplos):     <span id="message" dir="auto" class="auto-stamp">
so ler parte da biblia que fal de riqueza
</span>
    
<span id="message" dir="" class="limited">
#RENÚNCIA TEMER JUNTO COM A EQUIPE ECONÔMICA VCS SÃO UM FIASCO
</span>
    
<span dir="" class="change-scope" id="message" >
ja percebeu
</span>
    
 Esses são apenas 3 exemplo de uma lista interminável de tags (que toda hora mudam tamanho, nomes e posições... infelizmente não funciona para este problema.

Comment: Olha, o que você quer é pegar o texto dentro da tag correto? Ou algo mas específico ? Pois o código está funcionando sim [veja vídeo](https://youtu.be/eb9tZ8vByM0)

Comment: Eu fiz o teste, e substituindo `<span[^>]+>` por apenas `<span>` todas as Tags ficam iguais, ou seja, a expressão regular funciona perfeitamente.
Pra ser franco nunca tinha entendi muito bem isso até ver esse exemplo. Fiz varias TAG Span com variados atributos e executei a substituição e funcionou igualando todas.